# RISC-V RV32I soft float lib calls MUL and MULHU instructions in __muldf3

Tags: riscv

I'm using current [riscv-tools](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools) to build a firmware image for the [PicoRV32](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32) core. The firmware requires floating point, so I'm using `-msoft-float`. This are the compiler/linker options I am using:

```
-Os -m32 -march=RV32I -msoft-float -ffreestanding -nostdlib -lgcc
```

in this configuration, __muldf3 is provided by (according to the linkers `-Map` output):

```
/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/4.9.2/soft-float/32/libgcc.a(dp-bit.o)
```

But this code is not compatible with the RV32I ISA: It uses the `MUL` and `MULHU` instructions!

**How do I get soft-float for the plain RV32I ISA?** Do I need to compile my own version of libgcc.a? Are there instructions somewhere on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, the "-march=" flag only affects the current translation unit, not the libraries which get generated at toolchain build time.

Although there exist "disable-atomics"/"disable-float" configuration flags for building the toolchain, there is no multilib option for multiply/divide because they don't affect the ABI; the assumption is that the execution environment can emulate those instructions.

To the last point, the latest Privileged ISA v1.7 is designed such that you can run mul/div code and then trap into the machine-mode to emulate the mul/div instructions (you can even trap into M-mode while running in M-mode!). You'd have to provide your own mul trap handler in M-mode (probably located in your own crt0 file and linked in at compile time).

I instead recommend you try the "--with-arch" flag. A recent patch supports the --with-arch flag, so it's possible to build a gcc that by default won't generate multiply/divide.  This will prevent libgcc from containing those instructions.  You can try adding --with-arch=RV32I to the gcc configure line (to do so, you'll have to modify Makefile.in in the riscv-gnu-toolchain).

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer! I've now added build instructions for a pure RV32I toolchain to the [PicoRV32 README](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32#building-a-pure-rv32i-toolchain). This includes a quick&dirty work-around for newlib/newlib/libc/machine/riscv/ieeefp.c, which would not build when gcc was built with `--with-arch=RV32I` because it calls `fssr` and `frsr` using inline assembler.

Comment: @CliffordVienna, thanks for the instructions.  Keep an eye on the latest pull requests to riscv-gnu-toolchain. We're trying to make generating an RV32I toolchain much easier. Ideally, in the future, riscv-gcc would use the multilib facilities to generate the different combinations.